# "Cannot call send() while not connected" with RPC websocket provider

Tags: polkadot-js, rpc, websocket

I will try to explain it briefly. I'm using Promise API to connect to few different RPCs (ws). Also I'm listening to an event connected on each websocket provider. When all providers are connected I call res to resolve my new promise that returns in my `connectRpcs` function. Then in other function I call:

`await ApiPromise.create({ provider })`

and wait until `ApiPromise.create` resolves for each provider. When all providers and APIs are set up I'm trying to call `api.query.system.account` for some rpc from the list and the rpc throws the error:

```
RPC-CORE: queryStorageAt(keys: Vec<StorageKey>, at?: BlockHash): Vec<StorageChangeSet>:: cannot call send() while not connected
```

I logged `provider.isConnected` for each provider and it returns `true`. Why provider says that I'm not connected to the rpc? any guesses? I can share code in `hastebin` to clarify some points.

Comment: Can you share the full code? I guess you are trying to call api.query.system.account before the conexion but I have to see the full code.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/XZpW5AbU - rpcs init

Comment: https://pastebin.com/J40qA0kB - index.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens is that trying to make the call `api.query.system.account` before connect to the node.

Review all the await/async, I have added and async inside of the Promise.all you have in the index.js file and it worked:

```
const result = await Promise.all(Object.keys(chains).map(chain => {
    (async () => {
        const api = chains[chain];
        /*
            RPC-CORE: queryStorageAt(keys: Vec<StorageKey>, at?: BlockHash): Vec<StorageChangeSet>:: cannot call send()             while not connected
        */
        const { data: balance } = await api.query.system.account('MY ADDRESS')
        return balance.free
    })()
}));
```

Comment: What's the difference between `async chain => {}` and your async IIFE?

Comment: Doesn't work anyways

Comment: You didn't have the async there, no?

Comment: I had actually. My bad that I rewritten code wrongly

Comment: Thank you man. I figured out what was wrong. I had no `await` lol